# GlobIterator list folders that do not contain

Tags: php, glob

I'm trying to list all folders that don't contain the file koala.jpg, I tried this method:

```
$iterator = new GlobIterator('/storage/websites/site/images/menu_slider/*/koala.*',  GlobIterator::CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME);

if (!$iterator->count()) {
    echo 'No matches';
} else {
    $n = 0;

    printf("Matched %d item(s)\r\n".'<br />', $iterator->count());

    foreach ($iterator as $item) {
        printf("[%d] %s\r\n".'<br />', ++$n, $iterator->key()).'<br />';
    }
}
```

Only Problem is, it only lists the files that do contain koala.jpg and i need to know which folders do not contain it. and also How would i get the value of * (in this case 235x141) for each?

it returns:

```
Matched 14 item(s)
[1] /storage/websites/site/images/menu_slider/235x141/koala.jpg
[2] /storage/websites/site/images/menu_slider/235x200/koala.jpg
[3] /storage/websites/site/images/menu_slider/240x100/koala.jpg
[4] /storage/websites/site/images/menu_slider/240x200/koala.jpg
[5] /storage/websites/site/images/menu_slider/250x200/koala.jpg
[6] /storage/websites/site/images/menu_slider/250x300/koala.jpg
[7] /storage/websites/site/images/menu_slider/250x400/koala.jpg
[8] /storage/websites/site/images/menu_slider/365x200/koala.jpg
[9] /storage/websites/site/images/menu_slider/470x200/koala.jpg
[10] /storage/websites/site/images/menu_slider/470x60/koala.jpg
[11] /storage/websites/site/images/menu_slider/480x100/koala.jpg
[12] /storage/websites/site/images/menu_slider/595x200/koala.jpg
[13] /storage/websites/site/images/menu_slider/960x100/koala.jpg
[14] /storage/websites/site/images/menu_slider/960x200/koala.jpg
```

Any Help Greatly Apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `dirname($iterator->key())`

also, note `basename(dirname($iterator->key()))` to get only last folder name if needed

Comment: sorry, im not that advanced. am i just replacing $iterator->key() with dirname($iterator->key())? Because that simply just removes the file name..

Comment: then enclose it in basename() - this will return only last folder name, instead of full folder path

Comment: oh awesome, any idea to only list folder names that don't contain the searched for file name?

Comment: you will need separate arrays, during iteration store all folders in 1st array and folders WITH file in 2nd array, then you will be able to find difference via array_diff function